# Selenium - Safari Webdriver click not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, safaridriver, mac

I'm taking my first steps in Selenium and I'm having trouble with clicking on elements in Safari:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, value="checkbox1").click()
```

doesn't do anything by the looks of it. I've looked around and found a workaround using `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)` which is hardly an ideal solution.

I've read that it was an issue years ago and has been fixed since then but I'm still encountering it for some reason.
I'm using Selenium 4.16 with Python 3.12 on macOS Sonoma.

Comment: I'm having the same issue too. Perhaps this is simply due to a recent update or maybe the setup you have leading up to our codes. May I ask how you have your .py file started?

Comment: @AidenDorantesBarnard sorry, I didn't see a notification. Do you mean my imports or something else?